# Module not found: can't resolve '../file'

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, electron, electron-vue

I am working with an app using [electron-vue](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue). In windows, `yarn run dev` just works fine. But then I decided to switch to Ubuntu 18.04 and now everytime I executed `yarn run dev`, it returns like this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/iaccs-login/router/OneTimePassword.js
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/OneTimePassword' in '/mnt/d/iaccs/iaccs-base/node_modules/iaccs-login/router'
   @ ./node_modules/iaccs-login/router/OneTimePassword.js 4:15-55
   @ ./src/renderer/router/index.js
   @ ./src/renderer/main.js
   @ multi ./.electron-vue/dev-client ./src/renderer/main.js

  ERROR in ./node_modules/iaccs-front-office-otc-voucher/router/index.js
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/OtcVoucher' in '/mnt/d/iaccs/iaccs-base/node_modules/iaccs-front-office-otc-voucher/router'
   @ ./node_modules/iaccs-front-office-otc-voucher/router/index.js 4:15-50
   @ ./src/renderer/router/FrontOffice.js
   @ ./src/renderer/router/index.js
   @ ./src/renderer/main.js
   @ multi ./.electron-vue/dev-client ./src/renderer/main.js

  ERROR in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./node_modules/iaccs-front-office-withdrawal/components/Withdrawal.vue
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../constants/Withdrawal' in '/mnt/d/iaccs/iaccs-base/node_modules/iaccs-front-office-withdrawal/components'
   @ ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./node_modules/iaccs-front-office-withdrawal/components/Withdrawal.vue 9:0-92
   @ ./node_modules/iaccs-front-office-withdrawal/components/Withdrawal.vue
   @ ./node_modules/iaccs-front-office-withdrawal/router/index.js
   @ ./src/renderer/router/FrontOffice.js
   @ ./src/renderer/router/index.js
   @ ./src/renderer/main.js
   @ multi ./.electron-vue/dev-client ./src/renderer/main.js

  ERROR in ./src/renderer/mixins/Auth.js
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../store/Modules' in '/mnt/d/iaccs/iaccs-base/src/renderer/mixins'
   @ ./src/renderer/mixins/Auth.js 1:12-63
   @ ./src/renderer/main.js
   @ multi ./.electron-vue/dev-client ./src/renderer/main.js

  ERROR in ./src/renderer/store/index.js
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './Modules' in '/mnt/d/iaccs/iaccs-base/src/renderer/store'
   @ ./src/renderer/store/index.js 5:0-32
   @ ./src/renderer/main.js
   @ multi ./.electron-vue/dev-client ./src/renderer/main.js
```

I already checked the files and nothing is missing. Is there something I did wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: make sure you import it correctly..use relative path for importing the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLVED!

It turns out to be a very simple issue. I've been using windows for too long, I forgot that Linux is case-sensitive with the directory and file names. I just renamed my directories and files based on my code and `yarn run dev` now works!